# Product name not changing when choosing a simple product from dropdown?

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute, simple-product, ce-1.9.2.4

Could anyone help? I m using Amasty Color Swatches Pro extension. On my product detail page short description and images changing once a color and size are selected.

Can anyone tell me why the product name is not changing from the configurable product name to the simple product name when a color and size are selected?

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, you may find it better to contact Amasty for support regarding this, as it is difficult for anyone to help without having the extension. The help topic _"[What topics can I ask about here?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)"_ says: _"Questions which involve custom code or extensions should include relevant code and, where applicable, an indication that the custom coder or extension vendor has been contacted for support."_